# After Nginx Unit, Do we still need ASGI like Uvicorn, Hypercorn, Daphne etc

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, django-channels, asgi, nginx-unit

I checked NGINX Unit documentation for deploying [FastAPI](https://unit.nginx.org/howto/fastapi/) and [Django Channels](https://unit.nginx.org/howto/djangochannels/). They did not use any ASGI like Uvicorn, Hypercorn, Daphne. Their [configuration page](https://unit.nginx.org/configuration/#python) also did not mention anything about using these servers.

[Updates to NGINX Unit for Autumn 2020](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-unit-updates-for-autumn-2020-now-available/) says:

> now, you can run ASGI apps, use multithreaded request processing with
> applications, and include regular expressions in your configuration!

However, [FastAPI Documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/manually/) and [Django Channels Documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploying.html) suggest using Uvicorn, Hypercorn, Daphne.

What is the reality here?

Comment: nginx unit is an ASGI compliant server; you're replacing uvicorn/hypercorn/daphne/etc. with nginx unit instead. It's a choice you make just like you'd make using either of those three or other alternatives.

Comment: @MatsLindh do you mean I have to install both nginx and nginx unit where nginx unit is the replacement for uvicorn / hypercorn / daphne etc. Or, nginx unit alone can do what nginx + uvicorn / hypercorn / daphne etc. does.

Comment: You can do either; there are features that nginx support that nginx unit does not; but if you don't need those features, you can deploy nginx unit by itself. See https://unit.nginx.org/howto/integration/ for information about integrating with nginx.

Comment: in k8s clusters, would using nginx-ingress as the main source for input traffic, while running all my deployments with each pod running fastapi on uvicorn with only 1 worker a good choice for low-latency applications like serving machine learning models?